# Qt QFileDialog Files Are Disabled

Tags: qt, file, select, qfiledialog

I'm creating a QFileDialog and I'm unable to select any files. I can select folders, but not files. I'm using PyQt5 but can translate between other languages easily so anything helps. My code below:

```
class FileSaveDialog(QFileDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent = None, dir = "", ext = "*"):

        super(FileSaveDialog, self).__init__(parent, "Save File As", dir, ext)

        self.setAcceptMode(QFileDialog.AcceptSave)
        self.setFileMode(QFileDialog.AnyFile)`
```

Comment: I usually use C++, so sorry about the syntax, but what if you use `QFileDialog::getSaveFileName` instead of subclassing `QFileDialog`?  I noticed Qt behaves a little differently when you use the "helper" rather than instantiating a `QFileDialog`.

Comment: I can't use getSaveFileName because it overrides the custom stylesheet I have for it.

Comment: You can also try changing the default `ext` to "\*.\*" instead of just "\*". "\*" works for me on Windows with Qt 5.2.1, but it may not work on other platforms.